# how to access website from a sub folder inside the root folder?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I am about to deploy a laravel project. I uploaded all the files and the website is working fine but the only problem is when i try to access my website i.e for example if i try to write `mywebsitename.com` in the url then public directory is shown which is because i have symblinked my laravel's public folder to the public_html folder. I don't have any idea about how to edit the `.htaccess` file in order to load the website with mywebsitename.com and not `mywebsitename.com/public`. My htacess files code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

my file directory structure  is shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L0DC.png)

please help me

Comment: Same question? [how to access website using a sub folder and not root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264080/how-to-access-website-using-a-sub-folder-and-not-root-directory)

Comment: yeaah but nobody answered so had to repost it

Comment: @ab.in do u know what to do

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with this situation. Please note that posting same question multiple time is spamming. You can open a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to draw attention to your existing question.

Comment: did you get any solution? If you wish, I could open a bounty on this question. For that please delete any one of the same questions you wrote.

Comment: can u help me by offering bounty to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59340961/12424555

Comment: @ab.in i deleted the question u told me to do

Comment: Can i know why there is public_html folder? and where is the domain pointed, I mean on root directory of the project or public_html?

Comment: Please provide your virtual host rules from http.conf file.

Comment: @JeffrinJose Did you find any solution? If yes please provide those as an answer. If no please try the answers and let us know the results.

Comment: @ab.in I did find an ans to the above question please look in the ans section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this question.

1.Copy all the laravel files inside the public_html folder including the .htaccess file and the index.php file which is suppose to be inside the public folder(keep both the files inside the public folder).

2.Then link your storage to the public folder using SSH, for that open your SSH enter id and password and change directory using "cd domains/yourdomainname.com/public_html"
then give the php artisan command i.e "php artisan storage:link" 
(note:- after changing the directory you can give all the php artisan commands like migrate and config:cache or clear:cache as you wish.

3.Now after the all the necessary commands are given you can access your fully functional website including the image display function if you type yourdomainname.com/public on the URL but if you type just your domain name then all the laravel files will appear on the browser to avoid this and to to jump inside the public folder directly create one more .htaccess file  outside the public folder but inside the
public_html folder the copy the below given code and then if you just your domain name on the URL then your website will be directly displayed

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ public [L]
```

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing it is an apache server. If yes;

1. Ensure your domain `mywebsitename.com` points to the `public_html`
2. Add a .htaccess file in your root directory(`public_html`) and paste this in

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use it with RewriteBase directive,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /public_html/ # or '/' only depends on your vhost config

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with apache server but the problem should be in the default index file.
For long terms considered, I advise you to use nginx or openresty, it's easier to configurate.