# How do I resolve the image rotation and image cutting issue in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, image-uploading, image-resizing, image-rotation

[image][image]

I have an already developed a Laravel web app. I've just discovered that whenever I upload an image taken from a mobile phone it rotates and if the image px is bigger than the containers then the image is cut partially as I have kept overflow as hidden. I have heard of the image intervention package but i don't know how to apply it to my app, if there is any other way to resolve then issue without any additional package then that would be of great help.

```
profile-avatar{
    width: 420px;
    height:700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:top-center;
}
```

the above given is my css code if anyone wants to help and want any other code of mine then please tell

Comment: Can you share the project link ? I want to see the problem on live.

Comment: well i am adding the screenshots of the problem above

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQMJe.jpg this is how the image is seen after uploading

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXsfo.jpg this is how the image was taken

Comment: @Abdullah Al Mamun

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a problem with the camera app? I mean it's a common issue with camera apps on android at least.

Comment: Can you share your image upload code ? @Jeffrin Jose

Comment: i am using  iphone 7+ my co developer has a android phone in his phone it is working fine and when i upload using my phone this issue is coming

Comment: @user3532758 this is coz of ios and do u think there is any solution for this

Comment: @Abdullah Al Mamun u want my controller code or the image displaying code

Comment: this issue is only found on ios devices

Comment: https://medium.com/thetiltblog/fixing-rotated-mobile-image-uploads-in-php-803bb96a852c

Comment: @JeffrinJose some android devices have this issue as well. You need to identify if the image is rotated and rotate it back to the correct orientation.

Comment: @jeffrin-jose I think this error occurs for your device. You can upload image from pc or laptop to check it.

Comment: While uploading from desktop devices its working fine its even working fine with android the problem is with ios devices@Abdullah Al Mamun

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59345551/12424555 @Abdulla Al Mamun please see this question of mine